# Formating SSD corrupted something

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, gparted

I was about to format my old NTFS SSD used as a shared storage for a Manjaro and Win10 dual boot system to ext4, but I ran into some problems and something broke.

Currently, I am running Manjaro KDE without Windows dual boot. Since I already deleted my Windows partition some time ago, I wanted to switch from NTFS to ext4.

My First step was to copy everything from the SSD to an even older HDD. Then unmounted my SSD partition via Dolphin and the partition vanished from the devices list. (This was the first sign something is going wrong) Next I started GParted, but the device was not showing there. (mounting the partition worked fine) Since GParted would not work, I tried KDE Partition Manager. The device was found, but no partition table. Creating a new table didn't work with generic "could not create" error. I tried the same from an GParted boot stick, but didn't work either. Then I found a post with a similar problem and I used dd to clear the mess.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1
```

Now I am at a point where it can't be mounted or listed by fdisk nor GParted. Only KDE Partition Manager can see it.

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions what to do next?

Edit (1): dmesg since last reboot.

```
dmesg | grep -i sdc
```

https://pastebin.com/9PJJZ69n

Comment: Is the drive connected to SATA directly or bridged to a USB port? For most of the time `Capacity 0` indicates a hardware level issue instead of anything related to the data on the drive. You may want to make sure the cable and connection are fine, and check `dmesg` after a reboot to see if there's any related error.

Comment: @TomYan As suggested I added the dmesg to the original post. The drive is connected via SATA directly. It worked flawless until I started tinkering with it. I guess a hardware problem is unlikely, but not impossible.

Comment: Looks very much like the SSD is broken and you can do nothing. You could try to put it into an USB case but I doubt it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every major SSD manufacturer has a disk utility program you can download.  These utilities will let you detect errors and complete wipe the disk properly.  I had a different, but similar issue with a Samsung SSD and using their utility to wipe the drive solved my issue.